# Coffeescript - assign if value is defined

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

What is the best way in Coffeescript / Javascript to assign a value to a object field only if that value is defined? At the moment, I have the following code to assign values to the fields of the ogData object. I want a field to remain uninitalised if the articleData's field used as the input is not defined.

```
ogData.title = articleData.title1p if articleData.title1p?
ogData.image = "#{articlePicDir}/#{articleData.imageFile}" if articleData.imageFile?
ogData.description = articleData.summary if articleData.summary?
```

Is there a way to do the same without typing the names of articleData's fields (which may be longer and may be often changed) twice?

Comment: What's wrong with  a `null` initialisation?

Comment: I didn't want the field even to appear in keys in case the value is null or undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it's a common case, you could write a function, but I only can come up with one that has the property you want to assign to in quotes. I don't think there is some syntactical sugar for that case (as you have stated, you don't want a `null` initialization). Here is an example of such a function:

```
propMaybe = (obj, prop, data, optCalc) ->
  if data?
    obj[prop] = if optCalc? then optCalc(data) else data 

propMaybe ogData, 'description', articleData.summary
propMaybe ogData, 'title', articleData.title1p
propMaybe ogData, 'image', articleData.imageFile, 
  (file)-> "#{articlePicDir}/#{file}"
```

It doesn't really shorten the case where you want something additional to just the data (as in your second case).